# How to store "/\" in a string in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

How to store "/\" in a string in C++? i dont know why it isnt compiling.If it is an escape character than how to deal with it?.Considering that i only want front and backslach in my string beacuse im using it as an operator.

Comment: Use a raw string literal `auto str = R"foo(/\)foo);` - see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 6):

> If it is an escape character than how to deal with it?

By escaping it. The escape sequence for `\` is `\\`. Or, you can use a raw string literal which doesn't have escape sequences: `R"(/\)"`

Answer (score 3):

You can store it like that:

```
std::string str = "/\\";
std::cout << str;
```

output: /\

Answer (score 2):

'\' is an escape character. To get a regular '\', you just need to escape the '\'. That is use "/\\" instead of "/\".

Answer (score 0):

You could decide on using [UTF8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) encoding then store the descending wedge, [unicode logical and U+2227](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2227/index.htm). So `"\u2227"` or `"\xE2\x88\xA7"` or even `"∧"`  if your compiler accepts it.

If you really want `/\` code `"/\\"` as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).